# Typo3 Version 8 login loop

Tags: authentication, typo3

I have a question regarding Typo3 Version 8 LTS. I've installed en configured TYPO3 through the installer tool. But when I try to log in after the installation the login process gets stuck. The only information I get is the login button displaying 'verifying login data..' with a spinning loading symbol next to it.

Can someone help me to solve this problem?
Thanks in advance

Comment: first inspect in the browser whether there are javascipt errors (or disabled javascript). then, also in the browser, inspect cookie-allowance and network traffic. if nothing unusual, inspect the server-log.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is all because of RSA auth. make sure ssl enabled in your server. If you're using in localhost then you can change the login level.

- Go to typo3conf -> LocalConfiguration.php
- Change below configuration:

  ```
  'BE' => [
      'loginSecurityLevel' => 'rsa', // Change it to normal
  ],
  ```

you can change this from the TYPO3 backend as well,

- go to Install tool -> all configuration
- Look in the BE `[BE][loginSecurityLevel] = rsa` and change to `[BE][loginSecurityLevel] = normal`

Instead of this, it would be great if you resolve ssl issue and keep your security level to rsa for better security.

Regards!

Comment: Thank You for the solution!. My problem has been resolved. Regards

Comment: Have fun.. keep coding!

Comment: I changed rsa to normal but it is not working

Comment: Did you face any error? you can share more about your installation