# Backend cannot be reached after Typo3 login screen

Tags: php, typo3, content-management-system

I am trying to install Typo3 on my Windows 10 computer and everthing goes well. Right after the installation (right before the Typo3 backend is supposed to open up for the first time) I get to the Login Page, type in the correct username and password and then tries to connect me to the Typo3 backend. However, all that I see is "localhost\index.php..." could not be reached.

I have tried the installation process on two seperate computers and I get the same problem with both.

Help is much appreciated!

Comment: Sure you are using the correct port?

Comment: Not entirely, which one should I be using?

Comment: That all depends on what your server is set to run. The default for http is 80, but idk how you configured your server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have finally figured it out!

1. Go to the file

   > httpd.conf should be here --> C:\xampp\apache\conf
2. Add these lines

```html
<IfModule mpm_winnt_module>

ThreadStackSize 8388608

</IfModule>
```

I can finally log into the backend. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thank you for your solution! Totally saved my day. Actually, the ThreadStackSize is configured in a separate configuration file in 
`"<XAMPP-PATH>\apache\conf\extra\httpd-mpm.conf"`

Answer (score 0):

In the windows, probably you will get internal server error while you try to get the login to the backend.

**Reason:**

Open SSL is not enabled in the local environment.

**Solution 1:**

If you're using XAMPP server, I have created the proper configuration here: https://gist.github.com/GhanshyamBhava/41d3a34acc11cec2a4828b0d4b2c840f

**Solution 2:**

You can go ahead and set the login security level to normal instead of RSA in the `typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php`:

```
'BE' => [
    'loginSecurityLevel' => 'rsa', // change it to normal
],
```

I would suggest create proper SSL configuration at live for better securiry

**Other solution links**

- [Can't reach localhost using XAMPP (typo3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57788852/cant-reach-localhost-using-xampp-typo3/57799831#57799831)
- [How to install Typo3 in Windows 10 with XAMPP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50043797/how-to-install-typo3-in-windows-10-with-xampp/50044158#50044158)
- [Typo3 Version 8 login loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50021280/typo3-version-8-login-loop/50021761#50021761)

Hope this will help you!